# why is my image getting cut off? -EDITED NOW ONLY IN IE

Tags: css, html

http://bmww.com/clients/phwm_sc_website/index.html

^ thats the link to the site being tested thus far. I took everyone's advice here and am working on removing the tables which i did for the head navigation. So now they are aligned side by side but the logo with the div needs to be higher but not the top is getting cut off.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="header" class="header2" align="center">

<div class="container3">

<div class="divrow"><h1><a class="ex1" href="index.html">[ HOME ]</a></h1></div>
<div class="divrow"><h1><a class="ex1" href="index.html">[ TEAMS ]</a></h1></div>
<div class="divrow1"><img align="middle" src="images/phwm_sc_logo.png" width="170" height="212" alt="logo" /> </div>
<div class="divrow"><h1><a class="ex1" href="index.html">[ STAFF ]</a></h1></div>
<div class="divrow"><h1><a href="index.html" class="ex1">[ GALLERY ]</a></h1> </div>
</div>

</div><!--end red navigation header div-->
```

and here is my css:

```
.header1 { position:relative; top: 0px; z-index:10;
width: 100%; height:50px;
background: rgba(0, 54, 103, 0.6); /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background: rgb(0, 54, 103) transparent;
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99003667,  endColorstr=#99003667);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99003667, endColorstr=#99003667)";}

.header2 { position:relative; top:10px;
width: 100%; height:80px; z-index:50;
background: rgba(210, 6, 46, 0.4); /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(210, 6, 46) transparent;
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99d2062e,   endColorstr=#99d2062e);
/* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99d2062e,  endColorstr=#99d2062e)";}


.divrow { position: relative; display:inline; margin-top:30px;
float:left;  }
.divrow1 { position:relative; display:inline; margin-top:-60px;
float:left; z-index:50; margin-bottom:-20px;  } 

.sponsor { position:absolute; top: 730px; z-index:10;
width: 100%; height:300px;
background-color: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFF
}
  .container1 { clear:both;
width: 960px; z-index:-1;
background-color: none; /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
margin-top:60px;
}
.container2 {
width: 960px; z-index:-1;
background-color: none; /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
margin-top:100px; }

.container3 {
width: 700px; 
background-color: none; /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
margin:auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}
```

I can provide more if needed...i know this probably is a simple fix but i am still learning. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS for divrow1 class has a typo. You have miss-spelled "position: absolute;" on line 134 of the CSS file. If you have the absolute spelled correctly the image will no longer be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the

```
overflow:hidden;
```

from `.container3`, your image will not be cut off.

This, however will distort your site. This is because the logo is too big, resize it to a height of around 190px and you'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks!! Now that seems like a silly questions with an easy answer...it did mess up the layout, but if i bring that image up slightly it fixes it and add a z-index

Comment: nvm...the z-index isnt working so it cant overlap :( grr another thing i need to figure out

Comment: thanks...worked in all browsers except IE. Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your .divrow1 margin need to be changed:

```
.divrow1 {
    position: absoulte;
    display: inline;
    /*margin-top: -30px;*/
    float: left;
}
```

EDIT:

You need to do little update to your layout, this is not the best approach but it might be the simple one:

```
<div class="container3">
    <div class="divrow1">
        <img align="middle" src="images/phwm_sc_logo.png" width="170" height="212" alt="logo"> 
    </div>
    <div class="divrow"><h1><a href="index.html">[ HOME ]</a></h1></div>
    <div class="divrow"><h1><a href="index.html">[ TEAMS ]</a></h1></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="divrow"><h1><a href="index.html">[ STAFF ]</a></h1></div>
    <div class="divrow"><h1>[ GALLERY ]</h1> </div>
</div>
```

Revised CSS:

```
.divrow1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.separator {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: The margin needs to be less because it needs to sit higher then the other divs...is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: My image is still getting cut off in I.E. and with the new code it completely changes everything in i.e. and everything but the header disappears

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
clear: both;
```

to `.container1`

And remove

```
overflow:hidden;
```

from `.container3`

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks, but its not working in IE...Now it cuts off the top and bottom

Comment: remove `display: inline` and `position: relative` from `.divrow1` and then it works in IE + Firefox + Chrome :)

Comment: Thanks...i am going to try this solution as well, but I discovered it was the transparency effect causing this to happen in IE. Once I replaced the background color from a transparency to a PNG it stopped cutting it off.